# Is Timer class KVO complaint?

Tags: xcode, swift3, timer, key-value-observing

How to know if a class is KVO complaint or not? I'm trying to add observer on Timer class property `isValid`, but it's not working. Is Timer Class KVO complaint or not?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should assume that a property is KVO compliant only if the documentation tells you that it is. The documentation for the Timer `isValid` property doesn't tell you this, so you should assume that it is *not* KVO compliant.

But it doesn't need to be. Only two things can change a timer's `isValid` from `true` to `false`:

- The timer is nonrepeating and has fired.
- The timer is repeating and you told it to `invalidate`.

Either way, you already know exactly what happened. In the first case, your own timer action runs. In the second case, your own code said `invalidate()`. Thus, there is no need to observe anything.

And if you have other code elsewhere that is in doubt about whether it is safe to schedule the timer, then you can just test `isValid` first.